# Завершение дочернего процесса после завершения родительского

Tags: python, python-2.x, python-2.7, multiprocessing

Есть код

```
import time
import multiprocessing


def worker():
    while True:
        print('HAHA')
        time.sleep(5)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, name='worker')
    p.start()

    raise ValueError('Test exception')

    p.join()
```

Если его запустить наблюдается такая картина:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "try-else.py", line 15, in <module>
    raise ValueError('Test exception')
ValueError: Test exception
HAHA
HAHA
HAHA
HAHA
HAHA
```

Каким образом организовать так, чтобы после смерти (SIGKILL, Exception, etc.) основного процесса, уничтожался и дочерний?

Comment: Когда реально SIGKILL приходит, проблема остаётся?

Comment: @0andriy, Да, запустил скрипт сохранил его pid и потом сделал kill, задача умера, а подзадача живет, тоже самое и через htop, киляю один процесс второй живет

Comment: [Python: how to kill child process(es) when parent dies?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23434842/4279)